# how to update/upgrade to latest version of aws-sdk using npm in a react js project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have following in my package.json file. I want to see if there is any new version of aws-sdk available and if so , i want to update it. how can i do this via npm in  my project.

```
{
   "name" : "app", 
   "version" : "1.0", 
   "dependencies" : {
         "aws-sdk" : "^2.739.0", 
          ....
}
```

Comment: When you Googled "npm update package", did you not find anything useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this symbol ^ before the package number than run this command

> npm install aws-sdk

so you package.json should be like that

```
    {
   "name" : "app", 
   "version" : "1.0", 
   "dependencies" : {
         "aws-sdk" : "^2.739.0", 
          ....
}
```

Comment: thanks, i just realized , it already had the "^" symbol infront of it. I have updated the question. so now to update it, will i just change the version number to ^2.8 in my package.json file and run the npm install aws-sdk command?

Comment: yes this's will update your package successfully

Answer (score 1):

**Check for new versions**

1. `npm outdated`, this will give you a list of all matching semver versions - then `npm update` to load these available versions
2. Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk (versions tab) to see which versions are available - then use `npm install aws-sdk@x.y.z` to update the package to the desired version